# Excel formula for concatenating the values for each row in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am trying to get following output in excel using excel formula only

My inputs are numbers between 1 and 10 in each row. I need the output to be a string containing the inputs separated by `or` in a single cell

```
A   B
1   1 or 2 or 3 or 4
2   
3   
4
```

Thanks

Comment: Which version of excel are you using? Newer ones have TEXTJOIN

Comment: I am using excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

*Given you are using Excel 2007*, I have put a few options below.

Unfortunately I don't think there is any nice way to do this with Excel's native functions - hence why they created `TEXTJOIN` in Excel 2016

**Option 1**
The most obvious solution is to explicitly write out the formula. If you only need to do this one time and there aren't many values (e.g. 4 values in the example) then this is just fine

```
=A1&" or "&A2&" or "&A3&" or "&A4
```

**Option 2** 
Alternatively, if you wish to use this a few different times with potentially many values. I'd suggest you use a **UDF** (User Defined Function). That is, write a function that does exactly what you require such that you use the function name on the worksheet like this:

```
=JoinWithOr(A1:A4)
```

giving the output `1 or 2 or 3 or 4` -- for example.

The code for that function is below. You need to open the VBA editor, add a `module` and paste the code in there to be able to use the function.

```
Function JoinWithOr(rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim result As String, orString As String

    orString = " or "

    For Each r In rng
        result = result & r.Value & orString
    Next r

    JoinWithOr = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(orString)) 
End Function
```